# How do we git push without some files?

Tags: github

This is supposed to be a simple problem but i could not find solution anywhere. Basically, I have a github large file system. I make a branch with git branch, edit something, did not touch any of the large files. For some reason, when I git add -A, git commit,git push origin branchname, it tries to upload all the large files! This is insane. Is there a way to git push without certain files?

Comment: Going on the assumption that you have a `gitignore` file?

Comment: does it mean that we do not do git add -A?  but git add file by file?

Comment: I already did the command git add -A... Could I git remove something? so that when i push, it does not push those files?

Comment: Do you have a `gitignore` file in place?

Comment: I have a file called .gitignore

Comment: I added the folder corresponding to ones in the large files, when I git add -A , git commit, git push origin branchname, it still tries to git push everything 500MB.....I am so confused!

Answer (score 1):

You should specify all the files you don't want to push in .gitignore.

In the .gitignore file, you just have to list the files with the patterns seen in here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.

ps: just be careful if you someday decide you actually want to push those files.

Comment: the problem is..... there are millions of such files..... Could I specify folder instead?

Comment: yes! in .gitignore you can just say which folder you never want to push.
Something like `.foldername/`

Comment: suppose I added gitignore in folder1, could I still do git commit folder1/important_changes1 (a folder)?

Comment: you could, if you use --force like in `git add --force folder1/important_changes1`. you just have to be careful not to forget them, because they won't appear in your `git status` log. Also, once you do this, folder1/important_changes1 will no longer be ignored even if it is in .gitignore file.